# Adding mutable radio button results to single text box

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

I am in need of some help with radio buttons and outputs to a single text box.

What I am trying to achieve is to get a selection of radio button results to answer in one text box without using php, so:

question 1:
what color? A1: blue A2: red A3: green

question 2:
how many? A1: 1 A2: 2 A3: 3

So if i select the first question as A1 and the second as A3 then in the same page the results will look like this in a single text box:

blue

3

hope this makes sense?

I have looked on forums and all over Google but cant find the answer.

If anyone can help of point me in the right direction I will be truly grateful.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these questions are on the same page, you'd have a markup like this :

```
<div class="question"> 
   <span>What color? </span>
   <!--radio buttons -->
</div>
<div class="question"> 
   <span>How many ? </span>
   <!--radio buttons -->
</div>
```

Here's the JS. You'll have to listen to the `change` event on the `type=radio` elements. The `if` loop is to check if both the radio buttons are checked. This is important because, if not checked, you'll get `undefined` one of the options have not yet been selected.

```
$(".question").on("change", "input[type=radio]", function () {
    var color = $("[name=color]:checked").val();
    var count = $("[name=count]:checked").val();
    if (color.length && count.length) {
        $("#results").val(color + " : " + count);
    }
});
```

`#results` will have results of the chosen options.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/88LTQ/

**EDIT 1**
For multi line output, you must use `textarea`. And change

```
$("#results").val(color + " : " + count);
```

to

```
 $("textarea").html(color + " \n " + count);
```

Updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/88LTQ/1/

**EDIT 2**
To get a default value even if nothing is chosen, some more variables are needed, which takes the first values of the radio button group.

```
var colorDefault = $("[name=color]:first").val();
var countDefault = $("[name=count]:first").val();
```

Then, take the `checked` values from the radios :

```
var color = $("[name=color]:checked").val();
var count = $("[name=count]:checked").val();
```

Then, check if the `radios` are `null`/`undefined`

```
color = !color ? colorDefault : color;
count = !count ? countDefault : count;
```

Then append it to `textarea`

```
$("textarea").html(color + " \n " + count);
```

So, your JS would look like this:

```
$(".question").on("change", "input[type=radio]", function () {
    var colorDefault = $("[name=color]:first").val();
    var countDefault = $("[name=count]:first").val();
    var color = $("[name=color]:checked").val();
    var count = $("[name=count]:checked").val();
    color = !color ? colorDefault : color;
    count = !count ? countDefault : count;

    $("textarea").html(color + " \n " + count);
 });
```

Demo  : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/88LTQ/3/

Comment: wow, thank you so much for doing this, much appreciated. I don't want to come across a picky but is there any way the information will be below each other. So the 3 will be below the blue? also is there  way that if you only answer the question as blue you get vlue on its own and the same when asking about the numbers. if you only answer 3 that will show on its own? again, thanks for your help, this has been driving me nuts ;)

Comment: @user2257140 glad to help :) please mark this as the right answer if u think its helped u :)

Comment: @user2257140 : you could use `textarea`

Comment: @user2257140 updated my answer .. see the **EDIT** section of it

Comment: @user2257140 this will now take the default value. checked updated answer. (**EDIT2** section)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this. The most important keyword is the ":checked" so you can filter out the checked radio button among its groupmates :)
http://jsfiddle.net/m9p5n/

HTML

```
<input type="radio" value="blue" name="color">A1</input>
<input type="radio" value="red" name="color">A2</input>
<input type="radio" value="green" name="color">A3</input>
<br />
<input type="radio" value="1" name="number">A1</input>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="number">A2</input>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="number">A3</input>
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id="singleline_result" />
<textarea id="multiline_result"></textarea>
```

JQUERY

```
$('input[name="color"], input[name="number"]').change(function () {
   $('#singleline_result').val(
       $('input[name="color"]:checked').val() + 
       ' ' +
       $('input[name="number"]:checked').val()
   );

   $('#multiline_result').val(
       $('input[name="color"]:checked').val() + 
       "\n" +
       $('input[name="number"]:checked').val()
   );
});
```

I used two input boxes just in case, so the codes are longer.

Comment: both you and  passionateCoder have been a great help and it'now working. really appreciate all of your help. I can de-stress now ;)